# Mirroring iPad Pro to 3 or 4 iMacs

Tags: macos, ipad, ipados, mirroring

I am a Praise Leader in a mid sized church. I have an iPad Pro 12.9 that I run Office 365 on. My music is all in Word, and I would like to put an iMac in front of each musician and mirror my screen. Keeping all screens in pretty close timing is very important.

Is there a way to broadcast content from an iPad to several Macs in pretty much real time?

Comment: Could you maybe put the iPad and iMacs in a group FaceTime call, then use SharePlay's screen sharing from the iPad? https://www.techradar.com/how-to/how-to-use-shareplay-on-macos-12-monterey-and-ios-154 (Zoom could work too, but you'd have to pay to remove the 40 minute limit)